# web service failing. java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out - Using Jboss 7.1

Tags: java, sockets, ejb, cxf-client

I have some issues with the following piece of client code.

```
private FlightSchedule loadFlightSchedule() throws ServiceException {

                if (flightSchedule == null) {        
                                logger.debug("flightSchedule is null in loadFlightSchedule");
                                String endPoint = null;
                                String userId = null;
                                String password = null;
                                try {
                                                endPoint = getProperty("schedule_url") + "?wsdl"; 
                                                logger.debug("In loadFlightSchedule, flightSchedule endPoint is " + endPoint);

                                                userId = getProperty("schedule_username");
                                                password = getProperty("schedule_password");
                                }
                                catch( Exception ex ) { 
                                                logger.error("Exception in loadFlightSchedule getting properties from configProps...");
                            throw new ServiceException("Unable to get endpoint for FlightSchedule from Config...");
                                }


                                URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL (endPoint);
            }
            catch( MalformedURLException e ) {
                logger.error("Exception in loadFlightSchedule creating URL...");
                throw new ServiceException("Unable to build FlightSchedule url from the endpoint.", e );
            }

            try {
                                flightSchedule = new FlightScheduleService(url, flightScheduleName).getFlightSchedulePort();
                //((BindingProvider)flightSchedulePort).getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_CLIENT_TIMEOUT, new Integer(300000));
                ((BindingProvider)flightSchedule).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", new Integer (300000));
                ((BindingProvider)flightSchedule).getResponseContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", new Integer (100000));
                                ((BindingProvider)flightSchedule).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userId );
                                ((BindingProvider)flightSchedule).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password );
            }
            catch( Exception ex ) {
                logger.error("Exception in loadFlightSchedule getting FlightSchedulePort...");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw new ServiceException("Unable to get FlightSchedule service.", ex );
            }
                }

                return flightSchedule;
    }
```

I have been receiving the following error message.

```
04:31:05,085 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (EJB default - 7) Interceptor for {http://airways.com}FlightScheduleService#{http://airways.com}getCancelledFlightsFromPreviousDay has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:461)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:364)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)
                at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.getCancelledFlightsFromPreviousDay(Unknown Source)
                at com.airways.pdlloader.services.clients.FlightScheduleClient.getAllFlightsFromService(FlightScheduleClient.java:42) [pdl-loader-ejb-1.0.jar:]
                at com.airways.pdlloader.App.load(App.java:82) [pdl-loader-ejb-1.0.jar:]
                at com.airways.pdlloader.App.automatedLoad(App.java:67) [pdl-loader-ejb-1.0.jar:]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:127) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:137) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:105) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:101) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://devetc-flights.lcc.airways.com:12080/schedule/FlightSchedule: Read timed out
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1430)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1415)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:648)
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
                ... 59 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1541)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1493)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1401)
                ... 62 more

04:31:05,248 FINER [com.airways.configprops.ConfigResourceBundle] (EJB default - 7) Config service URL is: http://devetc-config.lcc.airways.com:11080/configuration/ConfigurationService
04:31:05,265 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (EJB default - 7) Creating Service {http://airways.com}ConfigurationServiceService from WSDL: http://devetc-config.lcc.airways.com:11080/configuration/ConfigurationService?wsdl
04:31:10,460 ERROR [com.airways.pdlloader.App] (EJB default - 7) *****General Exception occurred in load.  Transaction successfully rolled back.  Printing stack trace...
04:31:10,461 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7) javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.

04:31:10,462 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)

04:31:10,463 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.getCancelledFlightsFromPreviousDay(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,464 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at com.usairways.pdlloader.services.clients.FlightScheduleClient.getAllFlightsFromService(FlightScheduleClient.java:42)

04:31:10,465 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at com.usairways.pdlloader.App.load(App.java:82)

04:31:10,465 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at com.usairways.pdlloader.App.automatedLoad(App.java:67)

04:31:10,466 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

04:31:10,467 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,468 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,468 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,469 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)

04:31:10,471 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,472 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)

04:31:10,473 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:127)

04:31:10,474 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:137)

04:31:10,475 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34)

04:31:10,476 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,477 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)

04:31:10,478 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34)

04:31:10,479 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,480 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)

04:31:10,481 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,482 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:105)

04:31:10,483 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:56)

04:31:10,484 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,485 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:101)

04:31:10,486 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,487 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)

04:31:10,488 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,616 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

04:31:10,617 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)

04:31:10,618 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,619 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

04:31:10,620 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,621 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

04:31:10,622 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,623 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76)

04:31:10,624 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,625 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)

04:31:10,626 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,627 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43)

04:31:10,629 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,630 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)

04:31:10,631 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)

04:31:10,632 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)

04:31:10,633 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101)

04:31:10,634 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60)

04:31:10,635 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132)

04:31:10,636 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,637 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,637 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,638 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,639 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,640 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

04:31:10,640 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://devetc-flights.lcc.airways.com:12080/schedule/FlightSchedule: Read timed out

04:31:10,642 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

04:31:10,643 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,644 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,644 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,645 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1430)

04:31:10,674 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1415)

04:31:10,675 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)

04:31:10,676 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:648)

04:31:10,676 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)

04:31:10,678 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)

04:31:10,679 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)

04:31:10,679 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:461)

04:31:10,680 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:364)

04:31:10,681 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)

04:31:10,682 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)

04:31:10,682 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)

04:31:10,683 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       ... 52 more

04:31:10,684 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

04:31:10,684 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

04:31:10,685 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,686 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,687 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,687 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,688 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,689 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,689 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,690 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,691 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)

04:31:10,692 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1541)

04:31:10,693 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1493)

04:31:10,694 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1401)

04:31:10,695 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 7)       ... 62 more
```

I have added the timeouts in my code as well as I have increased the socket timeout in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="100000"/>
        </subsystem>
```

Any help with this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the URL [http://devetc-flights.lcc.airways.com:12080/schedule/FlightSchedule] accessible from the server where this code is executing?

Comment: Yes, the WSDL URL is working fine. The code works fine too for most of the flights. Intermittently, it is timing out. I had increased the socket timeout on the server too. Still doesn't work.BTW, how do we resolve the following type of error.  22:10:31,979 ERROR [com.airways.pdlloader.services.clients.FlifoClient] (EJB default - 1) flightInfo org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy@58928352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your timeout is too short, or something went wrong at the server end so your timeout got triggered.

Timeout intervals should be long enough that the server has plenty of time to do what it has to do, so that a timeout really means a server failure rather than just a loaded server or a complex request. You can start by setting it to double the expected service time, but the right value can be a matter of trial and error if service times vary widely. You need something more than three standard deviations from the mean so as to include as many success cases as possible.

Having said all that, you have 100 seconds, which should be long enough for most purposes. So maybe this really was a server failure. You would have to examine the server logs to be sure.